Lower bounds for a problem in Diophantine approximation
Suppose that $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_k$ are real numbers such that $1,\alpha_1,...,\alpha_k$ are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. What lower bounds (perhaps popular or recent) are known for
\begin{align}
\|h_1\alpha_1 + .... + h_k\alpha_k\|,
\end{align}
where $(h_1,...,h_k) \in \mathbb{Z}^k$? For each real number $x$, we define $\|x\| := \min_{n\in\mathbb{Z}} |x-n|$.

What is meant by the angle brackets, $\langle x\rangle$?

Hi @GerryMyerson! It is the distance to the closest integer. I have added it to the question.

without further hypotheses on the $\alpha_i$ no nonzero lower bound is possible even for $k=1$, because $\alpha_1$ can be taken to have arbitrarily close rational approximations.  For example, take $\alpha_1 = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 10^{-c_n}$ with ${c_n}$ increasing arbitrarily fast, and $h_1 = 10^{c_n}$.

Thanks @NoamD.Elkies! Would anything be known for the sequence given by $\alpha_i = \frac{\ln(i+1)}{2\pi}$?

I changed $\langle x\rangle$ to the more standard $|x|$.

The numbers $\alpha_i = \frac{\ln(i+1)}{2\pi}$ are not linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$. For example, $\alpha_3=2\alpha_1$.

Thanks @GHfromMO @NoamD.Elkies! I guess I was essentially trying to understand  exercise 4 in Noam's lecture note : https://people.math.harvard.edu/~elkies/M229.22/weyl.pdf. Of course, it would be great if you could explain!

For that exercise use the Euler product expansion of $\zeta(s)$. That is, use that the logarithms of prime numbers are linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$.

For the sequence $\alpha_i = \frac{\ln(i+1)}{2\pi}$, while not linearly independent over $\mathbb{Q}$, one may solve the exercise using Dirichlet's simultaneous approximation theorem. This approach would not involve Euler's product formula. It would be nice if it were known from an integer/convex programming approach the dependence of $||h_1\alpha_1 + ... + h_k\alpha_k||$ on lattice points $(h_1,...,h_k)$. It would be interesting to know which propositions are true and which are false.

Would any lower bounds for $||h_1\alpha_1+...+h_k\alpha_k||$
be known for the sequence $\alpha_i= \ln(p_i)$
, in which $p_i$
is the $i$
th prime number?
